# Join in Entity Framework returns unexpected value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I have this query

```
var q = from internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail in _ctx.InternalMaterialIssueVoucherDetails
        where internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail.InternalMaterialIssueVoucherId == Id
        join line in _ctx.Lines on internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail.LineId equals line.Id 
        join material in _ctx.Materials on line.Id equals material.LineId
```

I have 1 record in `InternalMaterialIssueVoucherDetails` and this table has a relation with `material` using `Lines`. In my `material` table I have 20 records, and the output is repeated 20 times with the same value.

Why? How can I solve that?

Here is the main query

```
var q = from internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail in _ctx.InternalMaterialIssueVoucherDetails
        where internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail.InternalMaterialIssueVoucherId == Id
        join line in _ctx.Lines on internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail.LineId equals line.Id
        join joint in _ctx.Joints on internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail.JointId equals joint.Id
        join sheet in _ctx.Sheets on joint.SheetId equals sheet.Id
        join material in _ctx.Materials on line.Id equals material.LineId 
        //join materialDescription in _ctx.MaterialDescriptions on material.MaterialDescriptionId equals materialDescription.Id
        join testPackageJoint in _ctx.TestPackageJoints on joint.Id equals testPackageJoint.JointId
        join testPackage in _ctx.TestPackages on testPackageJoint.TestPackageId equals testPackage.Id
        select new ViewIMIV()
                   {
                      // ItemCode = materialDescription.ItemCode,
                      // MaterialDescription = materialDescription.Description,
                      SheetNumber = sheet.SheetNumber,
                      LineNumber = line.LineNumber,
                      TestPackageNumber = testPackage.PackageNumber,
                      QuantityDeliverToMember = internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail.QuantityDeliverToMember.ToString(),
                      //Size = materialDescription.Size1
                   };
```

Comment: Where is your select clause ? Please post the complete query.

Comment: @user3185569 it noisy do you need that?

Comment: @user3185569 i updated the post

Comment: First off, you should use navigation properties instead of manual joins. With manual joins it's hard to follow the relationship cardinality. But guessing based on the field names used in the joins, looks like you have some many-to-many relationships included which normally multiply in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
(from ........
select new
{
    ItemCode = materialDescription.ItemCode,
    MaterialDescription = materialDescription.Description,
    SheetNumber = sheet.SheetNumber,
    LineNumber = line.LineNumber,
    TestPackageNumber = testPackage.PackageNumber,
    QuantityDeliverToMember = internalMaterialIssueVocherDetail.QuantityDeliverToMember.ToString(),
    Size = materialDescription.Size1
}).Distinct().Select(x => new ViewIMIV()
{
    ItemCode = x.ItemCode,
    MaterialDescription = x.MaterialDescription,
    SheetNumber = x.SheetNumber,
    LineNumber = x.LineNumber,
    TestPackageNumber = x.TestPackageNumber,
    QuantityDeliverToMember = x.QuantityDeliverToMember,
    Size = x.Size
}).ToList();
```

Comment: The result of my function is iqueryable

Comment: @MehrdadGhaffari Why IQueryable ? Any specific valid reason ?